# How to remove Skype timestamps in chat logs using VIM?

Tags: vim, text

I have some Skype chatlogs that I want to clean up. They look like this:

```
[12-12-6 下午1:54:53] Xerxes: Bla Bla 
[12-12-6 下午1:55:23] Aron: Bla Bla Bla
[12-12-6 下午1:55:29] Aron: Bla
```

What command can I use in VIM to delete everything in brackets [] (including the brackets themselves)?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to substitution:

```
:%norm da]x
```

Explanation:

- `:normal {commands}` runs a `{commands`} in normal mode for a line
- `:norm` is short for `:normal`
- `:%norm` runs the `:normal` command on every line of the file
- `da]` deletes the `[]` block at the start of the line
- `x` deletes the space that follows the `]`

For more help see:

```
:h range
:h :norm
:h a]
:h d
:h x
```

Comment: I like solutions that use the norm command over recorded macros and 999@@ because for large files, macro playback can be slow. :%norm temporarily turns off the display, so it goes quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, starting with your cursor on the first [ you can do this:

```
d%xj
```

where:

- `d%` deletes to the matching brace
- `x` deletes the trailing space
- `j` moves down to the next line

Further, you can record it as a macro:

```
qqd%xjq
```

and then play it back quickly with `@@` on every line (or `99@@` to repeat it for 99 lines, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Just a [substitute](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) will do:

```
:%s/^\[.*\] //g
```

Comment: Could you explain the function of the various symbols you are using?

Comment: "%" - apply for all lines, "s" - shortcut for substitute command, "g" - for all occurrences of the search pattern in a line, "^\[.*\] " - search pattern, "" (empty string) - string to replace the pattern with, "/" is a separator that separates parts of the command.

Comment: It won't work if someone's name begins with "[" and contains a "]", either.

Comment: Better version: `:%s/^\[[^]]\+] `. No `g` flag, no replacement, removes just the date in square brackets.

Comment: One more version `:%s/^\[.*\{-}\]//`; the item before `\{-}` matches as few times as possible.